# Git: Merging changes after branching before a revert

Tags: git

I've gotten myself into quite a tangle.

I committed a restructuring change that significantly reduced functionality to `master`. (I recognise that this was a mistake.)

This started to cause problems, because it was unfeasible to use the program with that change applied, but I had already committed further, unrelated improvements to `master`.

So, I reverted the restructuring change on `master`, and started a new branch (say `restructure`) based off the commit *before* the revert.

The problem now is that further valuable commits have since been made to `master` that I would like to pull in to `restructure` to ease its development. But `git merge` tries to apply the revert of the initial restructuring — oops!

I'm not sure what to do now, and I feel like a bad decision now could vastly complicate the merge back in to `master` later on.

To complicate things further, the `restructure` branch has been pushed. However, I don't mind having to use `git push --force` if it'll clear up all this mess; only a few people have pulled the repository since.

I accept that the true solution to this may fail to be an answer to the question asked — this definitely feels like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) scenario — but I had to put *something* in the title :)

**Note:** I realise all this is symptomatic of a bad git workflow, and this is certainly incentive enough for me to do things more properly in the future. However, I can't retroactively not have done the wrong thing, so my problem remains :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have not pushed master (?) and even if you have are also ok to force push and rewrite the history, you can just `git rebase -i` in master and remove the restructuring commit itself rather than reverting and then create the `restructure` branch from master itself ( since you are going to merge anyway) and work on it.

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly; `master` had indeed been pushed, but I figure a single `--force` now is less disruptive than the problems this was causing already...

Answer (score 3):

You can use git cherry-pick to pick just the commits you want over to the new branch from master. It will only bring over the changes in the hash tag specified. Check out the man page for git-cherry-pick.

Comment: Yeah, I tried this before, and it *does* bring the right changes over to `restructure`, but after trying to merge things back into `master` (just locally, to check that the cherry-picking hadn't broken anything), everything seemed to fall apart even more than previously. Admittedly, this is quite arguably a separate problem to the one asked...

Comment: Once you pick the good commits off master, reset master (not revert) back to the commit before the restructuring. So long as you didn't push master, you can safely delete all the commits after the last good one. Then the tip of master will correspond to the start of restructure, so when you merge it together you should get what you want.

Comment: It goes without saying, backup this repository before you start deleting commits for good :)

Comment: But all the commits *after* the restructuring on `master`, apart from the restructuring, should stay on `master`; I just want to pull them in to `restructure` as well. And unfortunately, the changes have been pushed, but there are about 5 people who pull the repository, so I'm thinking that the path of least resistance might be to eliminate the original restructuring commit and the revert and `git push --force` it...

Comment: Right, think of it this way -- you need to go back on master before restructuring, delete everything ahead of that, and cherry-pick the good things off restructuring that you cherry-picked over to begin with. Think of restructuring as a temporary holding ground for those good commits, plus the permanent home of the restructuring.

Comment: I've ended up doing it with a rebase on `master` instead as manojlds suggested, since it seems more direct and equally "destructive", but I think that would have worked fine too. Thanks for all your help, though — it helped me figure out exactly what the problem was and how to go about fixing these things in general. I'd vote you up if Stack Overflow thought I was popular enough to... :)